# Can I stack an Arduino to another Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, clones

I'm using Arduino clones, which have pin headers the same as Arduino's shields have (with extended "legs" below the board to be stackable).

Can I stack my Arduino (Mega) clone to an Arduino (Uno) clone without destroying both? Wouldn't it explode or something?

Just asking before trying it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a curiosity question or do you have a goal in mind? Just curious....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think that is a good idea. You would basically short the pins of each of them together, plus their power supplies. The only way it might conceivably work was if one Arduino had all its pins as inputs and the other as outputs, otherwise they would be "fighting" each other to drive a pin high or low. You would also have connected together their Reset pins so they would both reset at the same time. And doing serial comms would be problematic as the serial ports would be fighting each other.

---

Also, uploading sketches would be virtually impossible, as when you started the upload, both would be reset, both bootloaders would try to read the incoming data, and reply at the same time. Plus, the Mega and the Uno have different uploading protocols. So at the very least, you would have to separate them every time you uploaded new code, to either one.